# Position redundant, new role same wage but salaried

Tags: salary, layoff

Our company is unfortunately taking the decision to make redundancy across there workforce...

I am one who is being affected, currently in consultation.. they are axing 2 main manager roles at site and rolling into 1.. where the 1 is expected to take on both the responsibilities..thus new role will also mean it goes from hourly pay to salary.

My issue being (advanced apologies to focus on negs) I am expected to be on call 24/7.. sort out cover for sickness as an wen despite if am at work, work weekends and over Xmas, shift patterns r exhausting at times..

Now currently hourly rate is great for double pay over Xmas, extra days u get paid for..extra hrs u get paid for.. BUT now they wish to move to salary on the same money I get for hourly per annual. Same responsibilities with minor extras..the 5 extra holidays a yr and the potential bonus do not seem incentive enough to me.
Either itd be nice for poor wage, but great hrs, routine time off and no work over Xmas OR a higher pay but with the bug bears along the way.. as in work/life balance?

I usually love my job and have such a passion for it..but on weighing it all up as a package I am so confused with what to do..

Id be interested to know how others would feel and what their choice may be and reasons why...
Do I take redundancy?
Or take the new position ?

Comment: "Do I take redundancy? Or take the new position ?"  We can't make this decision for you.

Comment: Sorry.. its more of a, what would others do in this situation.

Comment: The question as written isn't a good fit for this format.  We try to seek correct/best answers.  Questions that are "what should I do" can fit into that.  Questions that are "What would you do" really don't, because the answer is inherently subjective.  If you are seeking useful information for coming to your own conclusion, you might be better off rewriting the question a bit to account for that.

Comment: Do not use abbreviations "hrs" etc on this site.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**The first thing to do is accept.  The job you loved is dead.  You can mourn it.**

It seems quite clear that they're trying to cut costs without reducing the amount of overall productivity, by making their workers work harder for less pay.  This almost certainly won't work as well as they hope it will, but in the meantime, the job that you've enjoyed thus far is going away.  The replacement job they're offering you... well, it's more work for less pay.  If they weren't going to try to make it more work for less pay, they wouldn't be doing it this way.

So, then, the answer is to consider your options.  How badly do you need a job?  How long would it take you to get a new one?  How do the jobs in your area for people with your skillset compare to the new (more work, less pay) job they're trying to offer you?  If the other jobs are likely to be as bad or worse than your new downgraded option, or if you simply cannot afford the job search, then you may be stuck.  If you think you can do better for yourself... it's time to go do better.